# Python: how to get rid of spaces in str(dict)?

Tags: python

For example, if you use str() on a dict, you get:

```
>>> str({'a': 1, 'b': 'as df'})
"{'a': 1, 'b': 'as df'}"
```

However, I want the string to be like:

```
"{'a':1,'b':'as df'}"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to accomplish this? The output of `str()` is intended for display, and is probably not what you should be using. Will you use that string in another program?

Comment: @spectras yes, that is the case, I need to sign the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could build the compact string representation yourself:

```
In [9]: '{' + ','.join('{0!r}:{1!r}'.format(*x) for x in dct.items()) + '}'
Out[9]: "{'b':'as df','a':1}"
```

It will leave extra spaces inside string representations of nested `list`s, `dict`s etc.

A much better idea is to use the [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) function with appropriate separators:

```
In [15]: import json

In [16]: json.dumps(dct, separators=(',', ':'))
Out[16]: '{"b":"as df","a":1}'
```

This will work correctly regardless of the inner structure of `dct`.

Comment: This. If the output is intended to be json, **do** use `json.dumps`. If it's intended to be whatever other format, **do** use the appropriate serialization function. And as a last resort, do it yourself.

Comment: The OP wanted single quotes, around the keys and (string) values, you have double quotes here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two spaces naturally occurring. `': '` and `", "`. So I think you can just replace them using `replace`

```
str({'a': 1, 'b': 'as df'}).replace(": ", ":").replace(", ", ",")
```

Note: To use this solution plz assume, you are not having `:` or `,` in any of the values or keys of the dictionary.

Comment: Since the separating `: ` is always preceded by a single quote and `, ` followed by one, you reduce the chance of a key/value containing the string by adding those to the replacement string.